# How do i get the function I made to run through a column data frame in a certain way

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I made a function that calculates a price change by taking the original price of something and the new price of that something, the function is:

```
#the formula is ((NewPrice-OrignalPrice)/(OrignalPrice))*100

def DeltaPC(NP,OP):
  DPC=((NP-OP)/(OP))*100
```

I want to apply this function on a large data frame I have which has a price column, but I need to the first price, then the new one, and repeat this over and over again until it does the whole column.

the column looks something like:

1. Price:1 2 2.2 3.2 3.3 2.9

---

Comment: Where's the original price coming from? Is it the first row in the 'Price' column?

Comment: It would help a lot if you add an expected output to your example.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but it seems like it's either [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) or [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Comment: if it is your own user function, then `.apply()` would work in a vectorised way.

Answer (score 0):

your function does not return **DPC**. can you try this ?

```
def DeltaPC(NP,OP):
  DPC=((NP-OP)/(OP))*100
  return DPC

df['DeltaPC']=df.apply(lambda x: DeltaPC(x['NewPrice'],x['OrignalPrice'],axis=1))
```